# how to get the attachments of the asset while working in offline with arcgis runtime.net for xamarin.forms

Tags: xamarin.forms, arcgis, esri-maps, arcgis-runtime-net

I'm using the offline mode in Arcgis maps by downloading Geodatabase and offline tpk with Xamarin.Forms. Is there any way to get the attachments of the asset while working offline with ArcGIS Runtime. And ArcGISFeature.GetAttachmentsAsync() method getting the attachments of Asset in online mode but this method does not work with offline mode.

```
await arcGISFeature.GetAttachmentsAsync();
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to get the attachments if parameters and layer configuration defines so.
Please take a look at two properties that facilitate getting attachments for offline features.

Setting that defines layer attachment download behavior for different layers while authoring data to be taken offline:
https://developers.arcgis.com/net/api-reference/api/android/Esri.ArcGISRuntime/Esri.ArcGISRuntime.Mapping.OfflineSettings.ReturnLayerAttachmentOption.html

Property to set ReturnLayerAttachmentOption
https://developers.arcgis.com/net/api-reference/api/android/Esri.ArcGISRuntime/Esri.ArcGISRuntime.Mapping.OfflineSettings.ReturnLayerAttachmentOption.html